# findOneAndUpdate() how $set overwrites only a few items defined in the query

Tags: mongoose

I am using the mongoose query

Request is executed, everything is good. But I want do so that if not comes Age - the his not rewrite. I. e. that it did not turn into null. Searched everywhere - not found.
Possible solution of the form
Age:(Age ? Age : this.Age), where this.Age is the current Age. However, I also did not find how to access the found element inside findOneAndUpdate. Thanks

```
updateAdmin: async (root, {FullName, Age, Email}, {Admin}) => {
const UpdateAdmin = await Admin.findOneAndUpdate({Email: Email}, 
{$set: {FullName, Age, Email}},{new:true,});
if (!UpdateAdmin) {throw new Error('Admin not found');}
return UpdateAdmin},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out useing the `upsert:true` method . 

And Update the set field to => `{$set: {FullName : FullName, Age : Age , Email : Email}}`

```
  updateAdmin: async (root, {FullName, Age, Email}, {Admin}) => {
const UpdateAdmin = await Admin.findOneAndUpdate({Email: Email}, 
{$set: {FullName : FullName, Age : Age , Email : Email}},{new:true, upsert: true});
if (!UpdateAdmin) {throw new Error('Admin not found');}
return UpdateAdmin}
```